# extend or expand element range contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to extend the contents of an element? Say we have the text "hello world of javascript" but currently only "hello" is contained in a  tag. How can we extend the range so both hello and world are now within the span tag while leaving "of javascript" alone?

Such as:

`<p><span class="bold">hello</span> world of javascript </p>`

Becomes:

`<p><span class="bold">hello world</span> of javascript </p>`

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit your question to include code you have tried so we may assist you in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the plain text that's into the <p> tag (i.e hello world) and put it 
// as the inner text of span
$('span').html($('p').text());

// Clear the plain text nodes of <p> tag
$("p").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; 
})[0].nodeValue = "";
```

Comment: but it needs to also handle a more complex example with a long paragraph of text. it should be able to literally extend the tag to one or more words and also retract it back

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using [`Ranges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

By setting the start and end of the range on the text node, a specific part of the text can be selected. Then, the text in the range can be extracted and added to the node you are extending. The text nodes can be joined back together by normalizing the nodes.

```js
const bold = document.querySelector(".bold"),
  container = document.querySelector("p"),
  range = document.createRange();
  
// selects the " world" from the paragraph
range.setStart(container.childNodes[1], 0);
range.setEnd(container.childNodes[1], 6);

// extracts the text from the range
const fragment = range.extractContents();

// move the text into the span
bold.appendChild(fragment);
bold.normalize();
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="bold">hello</span> world of javascript </p>
```